# Why is my temporary pointer's next changing from null to some other garbage?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm implementing a queue as a linked list and I'm trying to understand the difference between a value type and a reference type. Hence I made `front` as a value type and `rear` as a reference type since it needs to point some node at each iteration.

While inserting 2 elements 1 and 2, the `rear`'s `next` is pointing to `NULL`. But when I try to display, at first iteration, node 2's `next` is `NULL`. But in the second iteration, while executing `temp = temp->next`, it is pointing to some garbage value. Kindly help me out with this problem.

```
// Queue implementation
#import "iostream"
#import "queue.h"
using namespace std;

queue queue::insert(int num)
{
    node newnode(num);
    if (front.x == NULL)
    {
        front = newnode;
        rear = &front;
    }
    else
    {
        rear->next = &newnode;
        rear = &newnode;
    }

    //cout<<"inserted"<<"\n";
    return *this;
}

void queue::display()
{
    node* temp = &(this->front);
    int i = 0;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        cout << temp->x << "\n";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

// Queue.h
#import "node.h"
class queue
{
public:
    node front;
    node* rear;
    queue insert(int num);
    void remove(int num);
    void display();
};
```

Comment: Using the debugger to step through your code line by line might help diagnosing the problem.

Comment: You didn't provide the implementation for the class `node`, that would be helpful. And a recommendation, don't use `queue` for your data-type's name if you are `using namespace std;`, you know `std::queue` exists and could clash, right?

Comment: You've got the terminology wrong: `rear` is not a *pointer*, it is not a reference.

Comment: I used debugger and couldn't figure out the problem.So posted here.Why so many negative points for that? Is the question that bad?

Answer (score 0):

Your pointer ends up pointing to garbage because `node newnode(num);` instantiates an object on the stack, which disappears as soon as the function returns.

Comment: But the first two values are printed correctly.If it was the case,everything must be garbage right?

Comment: No, you are in the realm of undefined behaviour, which means anything could happen including that it may appear to work.